# Remove items from array without looping

Tags: php

Is there a way to eliminate more than one items from array without looping through it ?

```
Eg: array(1,3,67, 78, 60 , 5, 34, 68);
```

I want to remove items > 50 at once

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: Because when there are many items, it will slow down the process

Comment: It would require thousands if not more to slow your process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use `array_filter`:

```
$array = array_filter(array(1, 3, 67, 78, 60 , 5, 34, 68), function($element) {
                                                              return $element <= 50;
                                                           });
```

The callback function must return `true` for those items in the array that you want to **keep**.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible to do without looping, however you can use `array_filter()` function in order to hide the loop

```
function remove($var) { return $var < 50; }
$data = array_filter($data, 'remove');
```